# Unable to set theme in latest MUI v5 with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a small, simple Wiki for myself; just started learning React, although I've been working with JavaScript before.

I cannot seem to set the theme. I am trying to set the background to black. I am doing this:

```
  const darkMode = true;

  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      type: darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
      background: {
        default: "#000000",
        paper: "#000000"
      }
    },
  })
```

And then rendering with:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
...
</ThemeProvider>
```

[codesandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-elgamal-nf9w2?file=/src/inc/Editor.js)

[github repo](https://github.com/coderootme/TinyWiki), although it's still very young.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: V5 now uses 'mode' for the pallet : `mode: darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',`

Comment: @Jamie_D: tried that. Didn't make anything different.

Comment: Remove the background props and just set the theme to dark ` palette: {mode: 'dark',}` This is built in ... See [Dark Mode](https://mui.com/customization/dark-mode/)

Comment: @Jamie_D: I tried what you wrote. Updated and saved the codesandbox project. The site is still white. Am I missing something more?

Comment: Updated in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CssBaseline to the child

```
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <CssBaseline />
...
</ThemeProvider>
```

See [CssBaseline](https://mui.com/components/css-baseline/)

Comment: Thanks! Too bad this information isn't given in the documentation for ThemeProvider.

Comment: As a side note however, the theme provider should be your App.js , providing the theme to all the child components, whereby all you would need to do is call `<CssBaseline />` in each child.

Answer (score 1):

your import is wrong, you need to import ThemeProvider from /material and not material/styles, like this:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
```